# Viewing files one below the other in Xcode

Tags: xcode, text-editor

In XCode, how can I view one file below another?  Presently I can only view files side by side.  Instead I want to view just 2 files one below the other.  I'm using Xcode version 4.4.1.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can change the layout of the Xcode editors in the View > Assistant Editor menu:

[image: Xcode View > Assistant Editor menu]

Either “Assistant Editors on Bottom” or “All Editors Stacked Vertically” will arrange the editors the way you want.